# I can't access the ID nested inside the ListView <itemtemplate>

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to grab the value of the checkbox every time a user checks it using the following markup:

```
<!---- <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckboxWattage" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" CellSpacing="-1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="Flow" TextAlign="Right" Width="300px">              
         <asp:ListItem text="" value=""></asp:ListItem>  
     </asp:CheckBoxList>--->
     <asp:Listview id="filterListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="" onitemdatabound="filterListView_ItemDataBound" >
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1"  value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UDF_WATTAGE") %>' runat="server"/>          
         <asp:label ID="LabelValue" AssociatedControlID="CheckBox1" runat="server" text='<%#Eval("UDF_WATTAGE") %>' ></asp:label>
         <asp:label Style="font-size:12px; font-style: italic;" ID="countLabel" runat="server" text='<%# "(" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CountofUDF_WATTAGE") +")" %>' ></asp:label>
         </br>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Listview> 
    <asp:Button id="wattagebtn" text="Apply" class="btn btn-danger" style="float:right;" onclick="wattageApply_Click" runat="server"></asp:Button> 
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="hi"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

code behind update! I think I was able to grab the CheckBox1 ID. how can I grab the checkbox value? When checked?
I will update once I find the solution for anyone that's having the same issue.

UPDATEEE FOUND THE SOLUTION. i had to put if(!IsPostBack){ }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {  
        dapter.Fill(ds);

        filterListView.DataSource = ds;
        filterListView.DataBind();
```

}

```
protected void filterListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {

    }
}

protected void wattageApply_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in filterListView.Items)
    {
        CheckBox cb = item.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;

        if (cb.Checked == true)
        {
            string ch;
            Label1.Text = cb.Text;   
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = cb.Text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, how are you *trying* to "call" it?

Comment: Please post your codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" 
                 OnCheckedChanged="ListViewItemCheckChanged" 
                 Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UDF_WATTAGE") %>' />
            .
            .
            .
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code Behind (VB.NET):

```
Protected Sub ListViewItemCheckChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim cb As CheckBox = sender

    // at this point the variable cb contains the user selected checkbox
End Sub
```

This will allow you to examine the last Checkbox the user clicked

Keep in mind there will be a postback on each click.

This will give you what you are asking for but is probably not the best interface experience for the user.

Typically when presented with multiple check boxes you allow all the user selections and then process the selections with one postback via some submit style button.  This would require:

- Looping through the `ListView`'s Item Collection,
- For each `ListViewDataItem` find each CheckBox via FindControl("CheckBox1")
- Check for `CheckBox1.Checked()` and act accordingly

**Addendum: How to Loop through ListView Items (VB.NET):**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    For Each lvi As ListViewDataItem In ListView1.Items
        cb = lvi.FindControl("CheckBox1")
        If cb.Checked Then
            ...
        Else
            ...
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Addendum: A word about Checkboxes:**

An ASP `CheckBox` doesn't have a value per se.  It's "value" is the Boolean "cb.Checked".  But there are two ways you can associate a value with `CheckBox`

1) If the value is not a security issue and not particulary lengthy you can add an Attribute in the ListView ItemDataBound event

```
Private Sub ListView1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then
        Dim drv As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem
        Dim cb As CheckBox = e.Item.FindControl("CheckBox1")
        cb.Attributes("some-legal-html-attribute-name") = drv("Some_dataset_field")
    End If
End Sub
```

You are doing something similar with this in your aspx:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"
    value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"UDF_WATTAGE") %>'/>
```

the above should render to something like this:

```
<input id="ListviewMangledprefix_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" 
    value="[value of UDF_WATTAGE FIELD]" />
```

Inspect the field in the rendered browser page and see if the "value" attribute is being rendered.  If so you should be able to access it in the code behind as:

```
Dim wattage as String = cb.Attributes("value")
```

2) Better and more secure would be to implement and use ListView1.DataKeys. But this is a much more extensive topic that you should research when you have time

Comment: I couldn't format the checkboxlist. the way I wanted to in the frontend. so you think its better if I used CheckBoxList instead?

Comment: If you can bind to it in a ListView then you should be able to bind to it in a CheckBoxList.  If you're using a ListView to mimic a CheckBoxList that not good design.  If you need to display additional data along with each checkbox then you have a reason to use a ListView.

Comment: yes I do have additional information. if you notice on the 2nd label. it binds UDF_countofWattage column. I guess I'll stick to ListView to mimic a CheckBoxList?

Comment: thank you sir for your advice! i wish i can give you a thumbs up but i dont have at least 15 points yet. lol I will add a button to the user interface.

Comment: You're very welcome.  If you haven't done so already - you will need to remove the OnCheckChanged call from each checkbox and place the looping code in the button click or command event

Comment: hi, thanks for getting back to me. i'm not sure if im on the right track or not. I am currently working on writing the loop, which i have problem figure out at the moment.

Comment: I made one similar to your loop. i put label1.Text = cb.text to try to grab the checkbox value. It didnt work.

Comment: making another addendum to my answer.

Comment: damn i still cant figure it out. whenever i put DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem; it says cannot implicitly convert object to system.Data.DataRowView. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: missing? no :) however VB options allow for implicit casting - C# apparently does not - you will need to use an explicit cast everywhere I'm using an implicit cast, so `DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) e.Item.DataItem` or maybe `DataRowView drv =  e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView`  I need to brush up on my C#

Comment: I found the solution!! thank you. couldnt have done it without you know.